# f differentiable at $ c \in (a,b)$ if and only if there exists $\psi$ s.t. $f(x) − f(c) = \psi(x)(x − c)$ which is continuous at $c$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I tried proving this using the statement

$$f'(c)=\lim_{x\to c} {(f(x)-f(c))/(x-c)}$$

then

$$ψ(x) \to f'(c).$$ Is this correct? then $|ψ(x)-f'(c)|<\epsilon$ which proves that when f is differentiable at  then $\psi$ is differentiable at c.